# Local Variable referenced before assignment inside of a class

Tags: python, object, python-2.7, scope

Here's the situation

```
class Person(object):
    NumRid = 1
    def __init__(self, name, rid = NumRid):
        self.name = name
        self.rid = rid
        NumRid += 1

class Investor(Person):
    pass
```

then I enter the interactive python session, and type in `from file import *`
and then
    Investor('Bob')
and it tells me that local variable NumRid is referenced before assignment, at `NumRid += 1`.

as far as I can tell from googling, NumRid should be in the local namespace of the class and accessible from the class function.... so what's up with this? do I need to declare both to be global; or is there a magic word I can type to make it look up NumRid in the class namespace if there is one?

Comment: The `UnboundLocal` question is asked like twice a week here, using the search and sorting by score should lead you to some detailed explanations (in short: you can't assign to variables defined in a surrounding scope, at least not like this). Another thing though; `rid = NumRid` won't do what you want it to do as default arguments are evaluated at compile time and thus `rid` wil allways be 0. Just reference the class variable directly and remove the redundant parameter...

Comment: Well, I want to increment rid every time a new Investor is created, and assign that as the default, while also having the option of a passing in a different value: I checked the behavior and it seems to initialize them all to 1, which as I understand it, is what you meant by 0

Comment: Yeah you're correct, the `0` in my prevous comment should have been a `1`. If you want to be able to pass in a different value, use a sentinel value as the default - usually you would choose `None` unless this can be a valid value. Then test inside the method if the argument is the sentinel, take the current `NumRid` if it is or the argument value otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the `__init__` function, there is no `NumRid`, and yet you are trying to increment it.

It should be either `self.NumRid += 1` if it is an instance variable, or `Person.NumRid += 1` if it is a class variable (or, to future-proof against renaming the class: `self.__class__.NumRid += 1`).

Answer (score 0):

When you're in `__init__` your scope is that function, not the class. So `NumRid` isn't defined in that scope. You should use the full name for it, `Person.NumRid` to increment it.