# Python: threading question using static variable and semaphore

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a multithreaded example with a static variable and critical sections.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to modify this code to reflect that?

UPDATE: This is a duplicate question of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338983/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-inside-of-a-class) and should be removed.

```
import threading

class async_(threading.Thread):
    a = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore()
        
    def run(self):
        self.sem.acquire()
        a += 1
        print("Done")
        self.sem.release()

bg1 = async_()
bg2 = async_()
bg3 = async_()
bg1.start()
bg2.start()
bg3.start()

print('Background started')
bg1.join()
bg2.join()
bg3.join()
print(async_.a)
print('Background joined')
```

I get and error:

```
Background started
Exception in thread Thread-49:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/np/t.py", line 12, in run
    print("Done")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

0
Background joined
```

Comment: You seem to be asking one question but the error you are showing has nothing to do with that question.

Comment: Did you mean: `async_.a += 1`?

Comment: async_.a += 1, otherwise python things a is local. + The threads should share a single semaphore, independent semaphores won't block each other from accessing the thing.

Comment: question on the code answer.  Would I be initializing async_.sem 3 times in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be modified to:

```
import threading

sem = threading.Semaphore()

class async_(threading.Thread):
    a = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        
    def run(self):
        sem.acquire()
        async_.a += 1
        print("Done")
        sem.release()

bg1 = async_()
bg2 = async_()
bg3 = async_()
bg1.start()
bg2.start()
bg3.start()

print('Background started')
bg1.join()
bg2.join()
bg3.join()
print(async_.a)
print('Background joined')
```